# Chrome keeps reporting it has crashed

Tags: google-chrome

04 with google-chrome-stable installed.

If I have had chrome open I then close it no issues.

Upon reopening I get a yellow box at the top everytime saying that chrome did not shut down correctly.

At most I have only had 2 tabs open when it has been closed

Does anyone else have this issue?

Thank you